# Dockerized .NET App - dotnet restore error

Tags: c#, .net, docker

I am working on creating a docker file for a .NET app. My docker file is:

```
# Build Stage
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0-focal AS build

WORKDIR /source

COPY . .

RUN dotnet restore "./webapp/webapp.csproj" --disable-parallel
RUN dotnet publish "./webapp/webapp.csproj" -c release -o /app --no-restore

# Serve Stage
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0-focal
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /app ./

#EXPOSE 5000

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "app/webapp.exe"]
```

During the build process, there is an error on the RUN dotnet restore line that says:

```
/source/webapp/webapp.csproj : error NU1301: Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
```

I created a local nuget.config file in the root dir of the project, but that doesn't seem to help. The contents of that file is below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <clear />
    <add key="NuGet Public" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" />
  </packageSources>   
</configuration>
```

Does anyone know where I am going wrong?

Comment: See : https://zimmergren.net/nuget-error-unable-load-service-index-for-source-unauthorized/